# How Do I Lock My Google Drive App (or files) on iPad?

Tags: google-apps, ipad, ios

How to lock my Google Drive app (or just one file on it) on my iPad so no one can view it if they find my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Google Drive iOS app doesn't have this feature.

There are alternatives that do implement a password lock, like [GDrive](http://appstore.com/gdriveforgoogledrive). However, its user experience seems to be overall less pretty than Google's own app.

As a marginally related side note, Dropbox iOS app does implement a password lock.

Comment: I can endorse GDrive for this functionality, as we have implemented this as a solution in my line of business.